# Small IRC library w/ message loop

Tags: python, library, socket, chat

So I felt like creating a small library to make IRC bots. It's separated in two classes. `TelClient` is a class that handles the low-level socket programming and message splitting for Telnet connections. `IRC` is a class built on top of `TelClient` which provides an abstraction layer for IRC bot development. Bots are built around a message loop, like shown in the hugbot example below. It's also possible to poll with `bot.poll(timeout=20)` to not block endlessly until a new message arrives.

One of the issues I can already see is thread safety: calling `bot.receive()` in two different threads messes up the messages coming in, because `TelClient` reads one character at a time. Also I feel like the `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__` overrides are dangerous and overkill...

`irc.py`

```
import socket
import selectors

if hasattr(selectors, 'PollSelector'):
    selector = selectors.PollSelector
else:
    selector = selectors.SelectSelector

# Splits at every ':' until it finds ' :'
# Last element of the list is True if it found a trailing message
def _my_split(raw):
    stt = 0
    end = 0
    trailing = False
    while end < len(raw):
        if raw[end] == ':':
            yield raw[stt:end]
            stt = end + 1
            if raw[(end - 1):(end + 1)] == ' :':
                trailing = True
                end = len(raw)
                break
        end += 1
    yield raw[stt:end]
    yield trailing

class TelClient(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port, *, debug=False):
        self.sock = None
        self.write_file = None

        self._debug = debug
        self._addr = (host, port)

    def connect(self):
        self.sock = socket.create_connection(self._addr)
        self.write_file = self.sock.makefile('w')

    def close(self):
        self.sock.close()

    def msend(self, message):
        self.write_file.write(message + '\r\n')
        self.write_file.flush()

    def mavail(self, *, timeout = 0):
        if not self.sock:
            return False

        with selector() as select:
            select.register(self.sock, selectors.EVENT_READ)
            return bool(select.select(timeout=timeout))

    def mread(self):
        buf = b''
        c   = b''
        while c != b'\n':
            c = self.sock.recv(1)
            if c == b'':
                return ''
            buf += c

        msg = buf.decode('ascii').rstrip()
        return msg

class IRCMessage(object):
    def __init__(self, raw):
        self.raw = raw
        assert self.raw != ''

        split = list(_my_split(self.raw))
        self.trailing = split.pop() if split.pop() else None

        split = sum([chunk.split(' ') for chunk in split], [])

        if split[0] == '':
            split.pop(0)
            self.prefix = split.pop(0)
        else:
            self.prefix = None

        self.command = split.pop(0)
        self.args = split

        if self.trailing:
            self.ctcp = (self.trailing[0] == '\x01')

        self._parse_prefix()

    def _parse_prefix(self):
        if self.prefix:
            self.sender = type('', (), {}) # Initiating empty object
            if '@' in self.prefix:
                # Assuming it came.sender a client
                self.sender.type = 'client'
                client, host = self.prefix.split('@')
                nick, name = client.split('!')
                self.sender.nick = nick
                self.sender.name = name
                self.sender.host = host
            else:
                self.sender.type = 'server'
                self.sender.nick = None
                self.sender.name = None
                self.sender.host = self.prefix
        else:
            self.sender = None

class IRC(object):
    def __init__(self, hostname, port=6667, *, debug=False):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'connected', False)
        self._debug = debug
        self.nick = None
        self.name = None
        self.realname = None

        self._hostname = hostname
        self._port = port
        self._channels = []

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'channels':
            attr = '_channels'
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr in ['client', 'connected', 'channels']:
            raise AttributeError('\'%s\' is a read-only value' % attr)
        if attr in ['name', 'realname'] and self.connected:
            raise AttributeError('Cannot change \'%s\' while connected' % attr)

        ret = object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)

        if attr in ['name', 'realname']:
            self._update_user()
        if attr == 'nick':
            self._update_nick()
        return ret

    def _update_user(self):
        if self.connected:
            self.client.msend('USER %s * * :%s' % (self.name, self.realname))

    def _update_nick(self):
        if self.connected:
            self.client.msend('NICK %s' % self.nick)

    def connect(self):
        if not self.nick:
            raise ValueError('\'nick\' value not initialized')

        if not self.name:
            raise ValueError('\'name\' value not initialized')

        if not self.realname:
            raise ValueError('\'realname\' value not initialized')

        object.__setattr__(self, 'client', TelClient(self._hostname,
            self._port, debug=self._debug))
        self.client.connect()
        object.__setattr__(self, 'connected', True)
        self._update_user()
        self._update_nick()

    def disconnect(self, message = ''):
        self.client.msend('QUIT :%s' % message)
        self.client.close()
        object.__setattr__(self, 'connected', False)

    def poll(self, timeout = 0):
        return self.client.mavail(timeout=timeout)

    def receive(self):
        return IRCMessage(self.client.mread())

    def join(self, channel):
        if channel in self._channels:
            return

        self._channels.append(channel)
        self.client.msend('JOIN %s' % channel)

    def part(self, channel, message='Leaving'):
        if not channel[0] == '#':
            raise ValueError('Invalid channel name')

        if channel in self._channels:
            self._channels.remove(channel)
            self.client.msend('PART %s :%s' % (channel, message))

    def send(self, target, message):
        self.client.msend('PRIVMSG %s :%s' % (target, message))

    def action(self, target, message):
        self.send(target, '\x01ACTION ' + message + '\x01')

    def pong(self, target):
        self.client.msend('PONG :%s' % target)

    def mode(self, target, mode):
        first = mode.split(' ')[0]
        if not first[0] in '+-' and not first[1:].isalpha():
            raise ValueError('Invalid mode')

        self.client.msend('MODE %s %s' % (target, mode))

    def topic(self, channel, text):
        if not channel[0] == '#':
            raise ValueError('Invalid channel name')

        self.client.msend('TOPIC %s :%s' % (channel, text))

    def kick(self, channel, nick):
        if not channel[0] == '#':
            raise ValueError('Invalid channel name')

        self.client.msend('KICK %s %s' % (channel, nick))
```

Example usage: `hugbot.py`

```
from irc import IRC

# A small bot that gives hugs in #freehugs on freenode
def example_hug_bot():
    bot = IRC('irc.freenode.net')
    bot.nick = 'hugbot'
    bot.name = 'HugBot'
    bot.realname = 'I give out hugs'

    bot.connect()

    #  Message loop
    while True:
        msg = bot.receive()
        print(msg.raw)

        # Make sure nickname is not taken
        # Will try hugbot, hugbot_, hugbot__ etc...
        if msg.command == '433':
            bot.nick += '_'

        # Once registered, join the channel
        if msg.command == '001':
            bot.join('#freehugs')

        # Handle server pings to not get kicked
        if msg.command == 'PING':
            bot.pong(msg.trailing)

        # Handle any chat message
        if msg.command == 'PRIVMSG':
            # Give out hug if hugged (/me hug [nick])
            if msg.ctcp and ('ACTION' in msg.trailing):
                if ('hugs %s' % bot.nick) == msg.trailing[8:-1].strip():
                    bot.action(msg.args[0], 'hugs %s' % (msg.sender.nick))
            # Handle commands (like 'hugbot !join #channel')
            elif (msg.trailing.split(' ')[0] == bot.nick) \
                    and (' !' in msg.trailing):
                args = msg.trailing.split(' ')
                if args[1] == '!join':
                    bot.join(args[2])
                if args[1] == '!exit':
                    break # Breaking from message loop and exiting
                if args[1] == '!ping':
                    bot.send(msg.args[0], 'Pong!')
                # Proof of concept. Do not use.
                # if args[1] == '!eval':
                #    ret = eval(msg.trailing.split('\'')[1])
                #    bot.send(msg.args[0], 'returned: %s' % ret)

    for channel in bot.channels:
        bot.part(channel, 'Goodbye everyone')

    bot.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example_hug_bot()
```